Excel: Worksheet.Calculate causes udf to run infinitely
I have written a udf returns an array that is inserted at the cell location.
the udf can be long running as it reaches out to a rest service to fetch data from a database.  so i added a button on my ribbon to do that.
Sub ReCalc(ribbon As IRibbonControl)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = True
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Calculate
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = False
End Sub

Without the ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation, worksheet.calculate does not cause the udf to run.
If i simply do Application.CalculateFull, it runs the UDF - but ofcourse will also recalculate other workbooks.  WHY does this work and above doesnt?
Before the UDF is called, i call this function to turn off automatic calcs and a few other things:
Sub BattenTheHatches(on_off As Boolean, Optional msg As String = "")
    Application.EnableEvents = Not on_off
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Not on_off
    If on_off Then
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.Cursor = xlWait
    Else
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    End If
    'Application.Volatile Not on_off
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not on_off
End Sub

Any help in debugging and resolving this issue would be appreciated.
